# How can i duplicate html div while foreach JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json Array with five Json Objects and they have title, description, date attributes.

And all the Information should display in a thumbnail
I have created one thumbnail layout in HTML.

How can i duplicate the Thumbnails while i foreaching the five Json Array?

I just can use JavaScript or JQuery for my work and i need the same funcionalty like angular *ngFor

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.clone()` to duplicate the thumbnail container, do your json data stuff and then use `.append()`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate string in for cicle and append it to Dom.

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"name": "John" }]');
var html = '';
for(var i=0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++ ) {
  html+='<div>' + arr[i].name + '</div>';
}
$('#someContainer').append(html);
```

Also you can use some template engine for example [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com), or any other you can find, this would made solution more efficient but you will have to include additional third party sources.